# Show only specific options when doing Implicit Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-implicit-intent

Sorry if the question is already asked, I searched a lot but couldn't find it.

My doubt is when I am doing implicit intent for sharing image/test it shows me various options like WhatsApp, Facebook, Message etc. However I only want to show 2 options e.g. Whatsapp and Message.

For WhatsApp I know the package but I do not know for the Message app in mobile.

So,

1. Is there a default package name for message app?
2. how to include 2 packages in the implicit intent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer of Q1:**

Use this method for finding the default package.

```
public static String getDefaultSmsAppPackageName(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        return Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT).setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        final List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        if (resolveInfos != null && !resolveInfos.isEmpty())
            return resolveInfos.get(0).activityInfo.packageName;
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Answer of Q2:**

```
 List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
                if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
                    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
                        String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                        Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text message to shared");
                        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject to be shared");
                        if (packageName.contains(getDefaultSmsAppPackageName(context))||packageName.contains("com.whatsapp")) {
                            targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
                            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
                        }

                    }
                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Select app to share");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[targetedShareIntents.size()]));
                    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Comment: what is the function  getDefaultSmsAppPackageName(context))?

Comment: Thanks thanks very much bro it worked . You saved a lot of time bro

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_BROWSER)
    startActivity(intent);
```